# Find Next Position and Velocity from Instantaneous Values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

To find the position of an object at a given point in time: $y_0 + v_0t - \frac{32t^2}{2} = y_t$.

And to find the object's speed at a given point in time: $v_0 - 32t = v_t$

So say I give the following values:

- $y_0 = 500$
- $v_0 = 2$

Here is the plot of $y_t$:$v_t$ as *t* changes:

1. 486:-30
2. 440:-62
3. 362:-94
4. 252:-126
5. 110:-158
6. -64:-190

If I'm only given a point and velocity on this curve and I'm not told what *t* is at that point; is it possible to find the next position and velocity?

So for example, say I'm told:

- $y_{i-1} = 362$
- $v_{i-1} = -94$

Now I need to find $y_i$ and $v_i$.

Comment: Your table (if correct) answers your question, does it not? Also it is rather odd to have fractions like $\frac{32}2$, why not just $16$? Further double check your equation for $v_t$.

Comment: @Macavity That table is calculated for reference using the *t* range 1-6. My question is given a line from that table can you find the next line in the table, *without* knowing what line you were given.

Comment: @Macavity Yeah sadly I was solving for *t* from $y_0$ and then just plugging t back into the original equation to find the next line. I had hoped that there was a shortcut that did not involve finding the current line number, but it appears there is not :(

Comment: If you need a hint, note $v_t$ is an AP and $y_t$ increases at each step as a simple function of average $v_t$ in that step.

Comment: @Macavity Really? Cause I came to the conclusion that it couldn't be done because to find the next line you needed to know the acceleration which requires finding how long the object has been accelerating for. I'm not sure what a "AP" is and maybe that's my problem. I can easily find the next velocity but I don't believe it's possible to find the next position without knowing *t*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25194/discussion-between-jonathan-mee-and-macavity).